# ¿Por qué "millón" no se puede usar como adjetivo, mientras que "mil" sí?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, adjetivos, sustantivos, números

Supongamos la siguiente secuencia de frases:

- Los siete primeros elementos.
- Los setecientos primeros elementos.
- Los siete mil primeros elementos.
- Los setecientos mil primeros elementos.
- Los siete primeros millones de elementos.

Una vez que alcanzamos los millones de elementos, el número ("siete millones") se debe partir e intercalar "primeros" en medio. Esto es así porque la palabra *[mil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PENxPxR)* se puede usar como adjetivo y sustantivo, mientras que *[millón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PG9g0pj)* sólo se usa como sustantivo. Así, tenemos:

- Los siete mil primeros elementos (uso como adjetivo).
- Los siete primeros miles de elementos (uso como sustantivo).

En cambio no hay una versión adjetivo de *millón*:

- <strike>Los siete millones primeros elementos.</strike>

Y de ahí para arriba, *[billón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5WQzD1r)*, *[trillón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aevmA76)* y demás, son todos sustantivos. ¿Qué hizo que la palabra *mil* se pudiera tratar de forma diferente? ¿Por qué se puede usar como adjetivo y el resto no? ¿Proviene este uso como adjetivo del latín o es algo más reciente?

Comment: Realmente, no es que *mil* se pueda usar como adjetivo: es que *es* un adjetivo. El sustantivo correspondiente es *millar*. Lo que sucede es que *millón* no tiene adjetivo correspondiente.

Comment: "Los primeros siete millones elementos" no me suena mal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los números relativamente pequeños como *cien* o *mil* son muy antiguos, existen y son usados de una manera u otra en el habla común desde hace milenios. Creo recordar que el numeral común más grande en la época clásica europea occidental era *miríada* (diez mil), que en griego provenía de una palabra que significaba "número vasto, incontable" (los griegos agrupaban las potencias decimales de a cuatro, según entiendo, igual que hacen los chinos y japoneses). Las palabras que designaban a los números, al ser de uso común, funcionaban con la misma flexibilidad que otras (por ejemplo, transformándose de sustantivos en adjetivos, o permitiendo que se formasen derivados de todo tipo).

Los números más elevados y menos usuales ni siquiera existían como palabras en la antigüedad (*millón* es del siglo XIII) y cuando fueron adoptados lo fueron como términos técnicos. Incluso hoy no hablamos con frecuencia de millones; en nuestra vida diaria podemos pasar de números tan inmensos salvo en dominios muy específicos. De ahí que estos números no hayan sido "flexibilizados" como los otros.

Answer (score 6):

En latín, los cardinales [solían usarse como adjetivos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_cardinal_numerals). Esto es válido para los numerales [***diez***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=diez), [***cien***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=cien), [***mil***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=mil) y sus combinaciones, que son los que hemos tomado del latín.

En cambio, los numerales [***millón***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=mill%C3%B3n), [***billón***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=bill%C3%B3n)... los hemos tomado del francés, porque en latín no existían. Y [en francés](http://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition.php?mot=million), solo están reconocidos como sustantivos. Así que imagino que esa es la razón (no soy una autoridad en el tema).

Comment: Jojojo, y encima me acabo de dar cuenta de que "millón" es un "mil" grande (mil veces mil). Perfectamente lo podríamos haber llamado "milazo". :-D

Answer (score 4):

Acabo de ver que el artículo [*cardinales*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=rqV8h362gD62vc21qB) del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas habla de este tema:

> 6. Las voces *millar*, *millón*, *millardo*, *billón*, *trillón* y *cuatrillón* son sustantivos, a diferencia de los demás cardinales, cuya función primaria es adjetiva; por lo tanto, **cuando estos numerales cuantifican por sí solos a un sustantivo, este debe ir necesariamente precedido de la preposición *de***: *un millón DE personas*, *dos billones DE pesos*; pero si, por formar parte de un numeral complejo, van seguidos de otros cardinales, el sustantivo cuantificado no va precedido de preposición: un millón doscientas mil personas. Lo mismo sucede si se escriben con números: *1 000 000 DE personas*, *1 200 000 personas*. Además, estos sustantivos numerales, cuando se usan en singular, deben ir siempre precedidos de un determinante: *Acudieron un millón doscientas mil personas* (no X *Acudieron millón doscientas mil personas*); *Mañana te devolveré EL millón de pesos que me prestaste*. El caso de *mil* es especial, puesto que pertenece a ambas categorías: mil es el adjetivo cardinal correspondiente al número 1000: *mil casas*, *mil personas*; mientras que el plural miles es un sustantivo masculino sinónimo de *millares* (→ [mil](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=KSewKKH9vD6E0PSwQ8)): *miles de euros*, *muchos miles de personas*, etc.